# Jackson XmlMapper Converting XML to POJO, node text's key is ""

Tags: java, xml, groovy, jackson, pojo

I'm trying to read in XML data from a service (and I cannot change the data) and having a problem with the Jackson `XmlMapper`. If I have XML like so:

```
<entry>
   <title type="text">W411638</title>
</entry>
```

It gives me back the following map:

```
title: ["": "W411638", "type": text]
```

I'm trying to turn this into an object using the following code:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
Entry entry = xmlMapper.readValue(xmlData, Entry.class)
```

And my entry class looks like so:

```
class Entry {
    static class Title {
        //String __;  //-- This is what I can't figure out --
        String type; 
    }

    Title title;
}
```

The problem is I can't find any way of getting that title text ("W411638") into the entry object. The type pulls in fine and I can get it by doing entry.title.type and it's correct, I just don't know how to get that title value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me as a standalone Groovy Script...

```
@Grab( 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.0.5' )
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlText

class Entry {
  static class Title {
    public String type

    @JacksonXmlText
    public String value

    public String toString() {
      "$type -> $value"
    }
  }

  public Title title

  public String toString() {
    "Entry [$title]"
  }
}

def xml = '''<entry>
            |    <title type="text">W411638</title>
            |</entry>'''.stripMargin()

def xmlMapper = new XmlMapper()
Entry pojo = xmlMapper.readValue( xml, Entry )

println pojo // prints 'Entry [text -> W411638]'
```

Fingers crossed it works for you too!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this problem using @JSONCreator thus;

xml

```
<x>
    <a b="c" d="e">CDATA Text</a>
</x>
```

X.java

```
public class A
{
    private B b;
    private D d;
    private String cdata;

    @JsonCreator
    public PropertyDef(Map<String,Object> props)
    {
        setB((String) props.get("b"));
        setD((String) props.get("d"));
        setCdata((String) props.get(""));
    }
}
```